Which corner joint type is the most precise in terms of 90 degree angle?
I am new to woodworking and am seeking some advice. I am working on a project where I am looking to build a corner joint that is as close to a 90 degrees angle as possible. The purpose is to build a test apparatus for a scientific experiment. Which type of corner joint is the most precise in terms of being exactly 90 degrees, and what would be the achievable margin of error on the angle? Finally, what would be the best way to measure the angle of the completed joint?
Thank you!
Edit:
Thank you everyone for the useful comments. More details about what I'm trying to achieve: I want to build a 12''x12''x12'' corner (3 pieces 12''x12'' forming a corner) with as close angle to 90 degrees as possible. I care about the inner corner angle. It would not have to withstand forces or impact, but ideally it should be sturdy so that it stays square over a long period of time (ideally years). I assumed wood would be the easiest medium for this, but I'm open to suggestions for better materials to use (MDF panels, or perhaps metal using CNC?).
Edit #2:
The accuracy that I need for this is within 0.05 degrees of 90 degrees.

joints accuracy are based mostly on the abilities of the woodworker building them...

...and the precision of the tools....

As others hinted, any joint can be made as close to 90 degrees as your tools and skills allow. In fact, the joint is irrelevant because you can alter the surfaces (e.g. with a plane) after glue up to achieve any angle. So let’s step back. If accuracy matters, why are you using wood (that can change shape over time)? What are the sizes of your pieces? Will the joint need to withstand any forces? In which direction?

Also, are you asking about the inside corner or outside corner?

Thanks for the comments all, I edited the question with more details. I'm basically curious to know what would be the best material and set of tools and techniques to build a 12''x12''x12'' "perfect" corner.
I guess I could buy something like a drawer box from a cabinet maker, but I just don't know how precise the angles on these are / can be.

Can you be specific as to how accurate you actually need to be? (ie, are you concerned about thousandths of an inch out at 12”, or is it sufficient to be pretty close to an average engineer’s square?)

"Which type of corner joint is the most precise in terms of being exactly 90 degrees" There isn't one, all of a half-dozen joints are capable of producing square corners. "what would be the achievable margin of error on the angle?" You could get, as far as is measurable by hand, essentially perfect results. This is especially if you factor in that you can tweak what you've built after construction using, e.g. a hand plane, as already mentioned. Using planing or scraping you can tweak a wood surface one thou at a time. 1/1000" is beyond perfect as far as woodworking is concerned.... [contd]

...but if you need ABSOLUTE accuracy, you need to get this made of steel or aluminium, and surface ground. Surface grinding is capable of achieving accuracies in the realm of 0.0001" (that's ten thousandths of an inch).

Now that you’ve specified the size and that it’s 3d (I was thinking 2 pieces!), I would rule out solid wood. Boards that wide can shift of warp over the years with humidity changes (unless under lab conditions and with a stable wood like mahogany). And you have an extra challenge because wood expands/contracts across the grain but not along the grain. So the third board can’t be glued to the first two on both sides. There are standard ways to deal with this, but imho it’s unnecessary trouble for your use case. If any sort of moisture is involved, I would rule out MDF too.

One idea would be to use a metal corner brace like this: https://images.app.goo.gl/udPbbtT1zxtRXM7n8. You could bend it slightly to correct for inaccuracies. Then attach plywood, platic or metal walls.

@stanch, a third board (IF used) would be attached on one side only so movement issues in relation to it are a non-issue — same as a plywood back isn't an issue for solid-wood casework.

@Graphus I was imagining a dado for rigidity  That’s why I said it’s more work. Maybe I am overcomplicating. Still wouldn’t use solid wood though

@stanch, at the most simple you can tack on a 3rd board as an equivalent of a gusset plate. But regardless, agreed, I wouldn't use solid wood for this given the choice.

I would second the suggestion to get this built out of metal at a machine shop. It probably won't cost as much as you fear, and the precision and stability will far exceed anything you could build out of wood and would stay precise for years to come. Moisture might rust the metal (depending on the metal, of course) but it won't impact the accuracy of the jig. Heat might expand it, but the temp swings in conditioned space will have very minimal impact on it, even less in precisely controlled lab conditions.

They say that wood never sleeps. (Even plywood or more processed sheet goods.) So I’d be finding a good local metalworker…

Thank you everyone for the discussion! I will indeed abandon the wood idea and go the route of metal. Cheers!

@user3208430 - I've wrapped these comments up in an answer. Please accept it so this answer can be closed instead of being popped to the top by Community User for generations to come.

Answering this question calls for non-woodworking solutions

To sum up the comments into an answer that can be accepted:

There is no particular woodworking joint that will give a more accurate corner angle than any other. It is all determined by the skill of the woodworker and the precision of his tools.
Wood moves. It won't be suitable for lab experiments that need precision.
Get this made out of metal. It can be machined to whatever tolerance is needed and will stay that way for decades, providing a precise platform for whatever measurements are needed.

